# Dar uma saída em porcentagem levando em conta as entradas do usuário

Tags: c, lógica

O programa pergunta o sexo do usuário, em seguida pedi a opinião sobre um determinado produto( sim ou nao). Como saída, ele deveria me dar o total de pessoas que deram sim e não, em seguida a porcentagem de cada sexo que deu sim(mulher) ou não(homem), porém no momento o programa da apenas a saída de quantas pessoas deram não e sim, mas não a porcentagem de cada sexo. Não sei exatamente como prosseguir.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, escolha, sim, nao, feminino, masculino, sexo;

    float mediamulher, mediahomem;
    sim = 0;
    nao = 0;

    feminino = 0;
    masculino = 0;
    printf("Bem vindo!\n");

    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {

        printf("Entre com o sexo, sendo\n1 - Masculino e 2 - Feminino\nSelecione: ");
        scanf("%d", &sexo);
        printf("Voce considera esse produto aceitavel? 1-Sim ou 2-Nao: ");
        scanf("%d", &escolha);

        if (escolha == 1)
        {
            sim++;
        }
        if (escolha == 2)
        {
            nao++;
        }
        if (sexo == 2 && escolha == 1)
        {
            feminino++;
            mediamulher = (feminino / 3) * 100;
        }
        if (sexo == 1 && escolha == 2)
        {
            masculino++;
            mediahomem = (masculino / 20) * 100;
        }
    }
    printf("Total de pessoa que deram sim: %d\nTotal de pessoa que deram nao:%d\n", sim, nao);
    printf("A porcentagem de mulheres que deram sim foi: %.2f porcento.\n", mediamulher);
    printf("A porcentagem de homens que deram nao foi: %.2f porcento.\n", mediahomem);

    return 0;
}
```

[Para testar o código](https://onlinegdb.com/QTyqC2Lm7)

Comment: Você apenas conta as respostas *sim* e *não*. Para resolver o problema deve contabilizar os *sins* do publico masculino, os *sins* do publico feminino, os *nãos* do publico masculino e os *nãos* do publico feminino para então calcular médias e porcentagens respectivas a determinado publico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geralmente a média se calcula no final do ciclo for/while. Da próxima vez, dê nomes mais concretos às variaveis, e.g., countSim, countNao, nHomens, nMulheres, etc. Sobre o cálculo, às vezes pode ser necessário fazer um cast. Da forma que está feito pode dar divisão por 0, então dá uma olhada nessa abordagem aqui (nao mudei nome de variáveis). Bons estudos!

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() { 
    
    int i, escolha, sim, nao, feminino, masculino, sexo;
    float mediamulher, mediahomem;
    
    sim = 0;
    nao = 0;
    
    feminino = 0;
    masculino = 0;
    
    printf("Bem vindo!\n");
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
    
        printf("Entre com o sexo, sendo\n1 - Masculino e 2 - Feminino\nSelecione: ");
        scanf("%d", &sexo);
        printf("Voce considera esse produto aceitavel? 1-Sim ou 2-Nao: ");
        scanf("%d", &escolha);
    
        if (escolha == 1)
        {
            sim++;
        }
        if (escolha == 2)
        {
            nao++;
        }
        if (sexo == 2 && escolha == 1)
        {
            feminino++;
        }
        if (sexo == 1 && escolha == 2)
        {
            masculino++;
        }
    }
    
    if(sim == 0){
        mediamulher = 0;
    }
    else {
        mediamulher = (float)feminino/sim * 100;
    }
    if(nao == 0){
        mediahomem = 0;
    }
    else {
        mediahomem = (float)masculino/nao * 100;
    }

    printf("Total de pessoa que deram sim: %d\nTotal de pessoa que deram nao:%d\n", sim, nao);
    printf("A porcentagem de mulheres que deram sim foi: %4.2f porcento.\n", mediamulher);
    printf("A porcentagem de homens que deram nao foi: %4.2f porcento.\n", mediahomem);
    
    return 0;
 }
```